# How to deal with <TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.> exception using requests in Python?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I've used requests with good results but with this particular url, I get a redirects loop break.

```
s = requests.Session()
page = s.get('http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
street_type = tree.xpath(r"//*[@id='ep533076']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/p/a")
print(street_type)
```

I'm wondering specifically if there is a way to assign headers for the request so as to avoid the redirect. I've tested the actual url and it looks valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The redirect is response sent by the server.  It is typically a HTTP `<301>` or `<302>` response, which says "hey, I know what you are looking for, it is over here..." and sends you a new place to look.  Yes, these can be chained together, and yes, you can end up in loops.  That is what the max redirect limit is for.

You can set the number of allowable redirects in requests using:

```
s.max_redirects = 50   # the default is 30
```

But this will not solve the issue.  In this particular case the server is looking for what kind of browser you are using and is redirecting you when it doesn't find what it is looking for.  You can imitate a browser by adding a `user-agent` field to the header.

**Recommended usage:** sets the header to a generic browser for the single request

```
session.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'My app'})

# returns:
<Response [200]>
```

**Original posting:** sets the header for the entire session, which is not necessarily what you want.

```
s.headers = {'user-agent': 'some app'}
s.get('http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm')

# returns:
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: In this particular case you don't need to spoof a browser user-agent, and I would recommend that you only resort to spoofing if necessary.  Instead include an app-specific user-agent; e.g. `session.header['User-Agent'] = 'My App'`

Comment: That's probably true.  I just copied it from firebug.

Comment: Also for the sake of completion should probably add that you can add headers to an individual request instead of the entire session using the headers kwarg.  `session.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'My app'})`

Comment: Also its `headers` not `header`

Comment: putting User-Agent is nice but I think this won't get solved if you're requesting like a lot of urls